# what is the exact difference between textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

what is the exact difference between textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldShouldBeginEditing. and i want to know in which scenario we use them(I know that they are called when we enter any thing into textfield. i want to know the exact time in which they are called when we use both in our program)

Comment: What information do you need that isn't in the description for these two methods in the reference docs?

Comment: @rmaddy Ofcourse it is there i said i want more clarity on them and difference between them

Comment: No, you did not say you wanted "more clarity". Neither of those words are in your question. As written, your question indicates that you didn't even read the docs at all. If you read the docs for these two methods, the question you asked will be answered. If you have a more specific question that isn't clear in the docs, then please ask a more specific question. The docs tell you the difference. The docs tell you when they are called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "shouldBegin" something allows you to say NO on the return value to prohibit the action.

A "didBegin" something says it has just started to happen and you need to take whatever actions you need to do at that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

A `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method requests permission from the delegate to allow the textField to be edited when, say, a user taps on it.

On the other hand, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is called when a textField begins editing content (i.e. right after `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, if allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Example: you want to make a non-editable text field, so you return NO:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

About textFieldDidBeginEditing:

> Discussion
>   This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just became the first responder. You can use this method to update your delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method to show overlay views that should be visible while editing.

So let's say that you have a text field subclass (and you want it to be editable) that while the user edits the contents changes the graphic (example: it wants to display a different focus ring while the user types), so you use it to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the tags (from Storyboard) for "username" and "password" fields to 0 and 1 respectively and then try to catch acitve field inside    func textFieldDidBeginEditing, it does not work!

```
**func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

{
activeTextField = textField
return true
}**

```
**func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

{
let value = activeTextField.tag
switch value
{
      case 0:
          // for username field it should execute this case
      case 1:
         // for password field it should execute this case
    }
}**

the same function is working and providing correct results when called as     @objc func textFieldDidBeginEditing, without "objc" word it is not picking the active field. I just want to know, why is so...

```
**@objc func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: ) -> Bool
```

{
activeTextField = textField
return true
}**